# Page refresh on modal confirmation using jquery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I have an AJAX function to delete a record from the database. My problem is once the data is deleted it stays on the delete URL. Instead, I want to redirect it to my listing page. How should I change my JavaScript code.

And my Script is:

```
  <script>
function confirm_modal(delete_url,title)
    {
        jQuery('#modal_delete_m_n').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static',keyboard :false});
        jQuery("#modal_delete_m_n .grt").text(title);
        document.getElementById('delete_link_m_n').setAttribute("href" , delete_url );
        document.getElementById('delete_link_m_n').focus();
    }
    </script>
```

and my HTML page with modal is:

```
 <div id="container">
 <div id="wrapper">
  <?php
   if (isset($success_message)) {
            echo $success_message;
        } 
 ?>
 <h1>Staff List </h1><hr/>
 <div id="menu">
 <table>
 <tr>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Designation</th>
 <th>Delete</th>
 </tr>
 <?php if(isset($result_set)): 
  foreach ($result_set as $username): ?>
  <tr>

  <td><?php echo $username->user_name; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $username->designation; ?></td>
  <td><a href="" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"     onclick="confirm_modal('<?php echo "delete_staff/".$username->staff_id;? >','Account');" data-target="#myModal">Delete</a></td>
   </tr>


 <?php endforeach; 
 else: echo "No Results Available";
 endif;
 ?>
 </table>
 </div>
```

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modal_delete_m_n"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top:100px;">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center;">Are you sure to Delete this <span class="grt"></span> ?</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer" style="margin:0px; border-top:0px; text-align:center;">
                    <span id="preloader-delete"></span>
                    </br>
                      <a class="btn btn-danger" id="delete_link_m_n" href="">Delete</a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" id="delete_cancel_link">Cancel</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Joachim : I will let you know once I do the above mentioned changes. Thank you so much for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work on structure in the code. In the `confirm_modal()` function you are mixing up jQuery with Javascript. It's better to keep everything consistent.

When you replace

```
document.getElementById('delete_link_m_n').setAttribute("href" , delete_url );
document.getElementById('delete_link_m_n').focus();
```

with

```
jQuery('#delete_link_m_n').attr("href" , delete_url );
jQuery('#delete_link_m_n').focus();
```

the function would become

```
function confirm_modal(delete_url,title)

    // About the modal itself
    jQuery('#modal_delete_m_n').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static',keyboard :false});
    jQuery("#modal_delete_m_n .grt").text(title);

    // About the delete button
    jQuery('#delete_link_m_n').attr("href" , delete_url );
    jQuery('#delete_link_m_n').focus();

    // Prevent page refreshing
    return false;
}
```

As a sidenote,

```
<?php echo "delete_staff/".$username->staff_id;? >
```

should not have a space between `?` and `>`.

Also make sure jQuery is loaded correctly, if not there will be errors in the console. One last thing, there is no AJAX involved in this piece of code. You are just updating the `href` to redirect the user to another page.